# Do racial origins stack?

Tags: dnd-4e, races

If I take a feat that gives me a certain origin but I already have a specific racial origin, do they stack or is my racial origin replaced?

Consider this example. Calistar the Eladrin is a fey creature, but he wants to take the Haunting Shade feat.

> **[Haunting Shade](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/display.aspx?page=Feat&Id=3064)**
>
> Your origin changes to shadow if it isn't already, so you are considered a shadow creature for all effects related to creature origin.

Is he a shadow creature, or both shadow and fey?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, Calistar now has an Origin of **[Shadow](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/glossary.aspx?id=18)**.

The *Rules Compendium p60* defines origin.  It doesn't say it explicitly, but the implication is that creatures normally only have one origin, much like they have one level, one race.

The flavor text in [Dragon Magazine #387](http://www.wizards.com/dnd/TOC.aspx?x=dnd/4new/drtoc/387) also strongly favors this interpretation, it says that to take this feat a character needs to give up his soul.

Answer (score 14):

I would interpret that specific case as "Your origin **changes** to shadow..." He is a shadow creature, and no longer a fey.

Comment: I like both answers!

Comment: @peterseckler The other one is good but only talks about implications and interpretations. This one is the definitive answer to me.